# Empty collection with rabl Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, null, rabl

I'm facing an issues when try to render an empty array from `rabl`

```
#app/controllers/recipes_controller
class RecipesController < ApplicationController

   respond_to :json 

   def unpublished
      @unpublished = Recipe.unpublished.for_user(<uer id>)
   end 
end

#app/views/recipes/unpublished.rabl
collection @unpublished
attributes :id
```

But my problem is if the `@unpublished #=> []`, my `rabl` template gives `undefined method`id' for nil:NilClass` error.

And I have done some search and I cannot find an easy way of doing it. I believe there should be an easy way, for example:

```
collection @unpublished
attributes :id , if => :id
```

Answer (score 0):

Rabl does not seem to have a solution for this. Your answer seems fine but it would get cumbersome if you have many attributes. You can have a conditional lambda for all the attributes as mentioned [here](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl#conditions)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
    if @unpublished.id.present?
       attributes :id
    else
       extends "you can create a file rabl for handle is {#api/error}"
    end

    example: error.rabl

    object false
    node :message do
      "some think went wrong"
    end
```

I hope this can help, :)